# Format error for copied value from Excel to PPT

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I have a value in excel cell with % sign, and - sign, when coping these value to the power point, the %, - changed in different format.

**Excel sheet view:**

-13,516

100.0%

[image]

**Power point view:**

13,516-

%100.0

[image]

Note: I tried all paste format, even as image or text. same issue.

Is there any setting i must do it.

Many thanks

Copy from excel and paste data in PPT